# Applying same VBA code on all sheets in a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a question regarding VBA.
I am trying to apply the below code to all the sheets in a workbook.
The workbook contains numerous worksheets but have all the datapoints in the same cells
The only difference are the sheet's names.
So Basically "MoneyMarket" is just a name of one sheet of the workbook.
Tried using for each sheet but got kind of stuck of how to apply this

```
Dim YRange As Integer, ProjectionRange As Integer
Dim XRange As Range
Dim I As Integer
Sub DrawChart()
    Set XRange = Sheets("MoneyMarket"). _
Range("R8:R" &   Sheets("MoneyMarket").Range("R8").End(xlDown).Row)
    ProjectionRange = Sheets("MoneyMarket").Range("T54").End(xlDown).Row
    YRange = Sheets("MoneyMarket").Range("S8").End(xlDown).Row
    Sheets("MoneyMarket").Range("S8:S" & YRange).Select
    Charts.Add
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="MoneyMarket"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=Sheets("MoneyMarket").Range("T8:X" & YRange)
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = XRange
For I = 2 To 6
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(I).Select
    With Selection.Format.Line
    .DashStyle = msoLineDash
    End With
Next I

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

a very quick search in Google will give you the answer on how to loop through all sheets in a workbook. This is just an example

```
   Dim WS_Count As Integer
   Dim I As Integer

     ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
     ' workbook.
     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

     ' Begin the loop.
     For I = 1 To WS_Count
        ' Insert/Modify your code here. It will be applied to each sheet.

       'For example to get their names
       msgbox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name
     Next I
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested on a loop across some sheets in a workbook, I recommend you use an array like that:

```
Sub loopAcrossSheets()
    temp = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3", "SheetX")
    For Each SheetName In temp
        DrawChart (SheetName)
    Next
End Sub
```

Then you should put the input string on your Sub:

```
Sub DrawChart(SheetName As String)
```

And, at last, replace the sheet name ("MoneyMarket") by SheetName!
This Works for me!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Module, and refer directly to `ActiveSheet` in your code, check the code below

```
Dim YRange As Integer, ProjectionRange As Integer
Dim XRange As Range
Dim I As Integer
Public Sub DrawChart()
    Dim ActiveSheetName as String
    ActiveSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
    Set XRange = ActiveSheet. _
Range("R8:R" &   ActiveSheet.Range("R8").End(xlDown).Row)
    ProjectionRange = ActiveSheet.Range("T54").End(xlDown).Row
    YRange = ActiveSheet.Range("S8").End(xlDown).Row
    Sheets("MoneyMarket").Range("S8:S" & YRange).Select
    Charts.Add
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ActiveSheetName
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=ActiveSheet.Range("T8:X" & YRange)
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = XRange
For I = 2 To 6
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(I).Select
    With Selection.Format.Line
    .DashStyle = msoLineDash
    End With
Next I

End Sub
```